# ReactJS render html for different pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react.js site created using: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started with the **npx create-react-app my-app** command. I got many pages in my app and when I open the rendered source code in google chrome after building the site. The problem is all pages are in one **bundle.js** including all text and HTML elements of all pages are in that file combined. Does someone know how to get the HTML rendered in the source code for all pages individually instead of having just a **bundle.js** for all pages content?

So the other pages can get indexed individually by google?

I hope someone knows how to get this working. If there is an npm plugin or an example site available please post the link. I really can't find a solution for weeks now, I just see a **bundle.js** in the exported HTML file that includes all text and images and HTML elements of all pages how can I have it rendered as html output instead of just all in one **bundle.js** for indexing purposes?

By the way: my app uses **'react-router-dom'** I don't want to break, the routing of the pages but having the pages being indexable individually.

Below is a sample code

---

App.js

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,
Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


import Nav from './components/nav';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';

import home from './components/pages/home';
import about from './components/pages/about';
import contact from './components/pages/contact';

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
        <Nav/>
        <Header/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={about} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={contact} /> 
        <Footer/>
    </div>
    </Router>

    );
}
}

export default App;
```

---

home.js

```
//home.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class home extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <p>content...</p>
    </div>
    );
}
}

export default home;
```

Comment: If you are looking "indexed by google" you should try Next.js or Gatsby, which serve your app as HTML individual pages... You can also use `react-loadable` if you want to import your pages only when needed but for what you posted looks like Gatsby or Next.js is the way to go

Comment: I believe that React and React Router are designed to create single-page application. Therefore you only need 1 static HTML page. Being indexed by google is a different topic I think, you should use a server side language for that

Comment: Thanks everyone, is there any chance to get the different pages indexed even when using server side Technology in reactjs. I could run node on my server 24/7 with no problems, it's I just don't want to recreate the entire site using another Technologie if there is an easier solution out there. I saw the official reactjs website and they have also routing but when viewing their source code all their pages have the elements rendered as html output to get them easily indexed. Do you know how to get that working in just react.js if not I'll probably migrate it to Gatsby soon. Thanks again for help